# adjusting side caption in latex

Tags: latex, caption

I would like to adjust the side caption in latex by having the caption flushed left (or right) and be aligned with the top of the figure.
Attached is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}    
\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
\caption{I would like the caption to occupy say 0.2linewidth and be left (or right) adjusted and on top}\label{fig:testA}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the caption either flush left or right, the `sidecap` package offers the options `raggedright` and `raggedleft`.

To align the caption with the top of the figure, you can use `\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[
%ragged
%raggedright
raggedleft
]{sidecap}   
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t} 
\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
\caption{I would like the caption to occupy say 0.2linewidth and be left (or right) adjusted and on top}\label{fig:testA}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, how about `\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{h}`? It seems does not work.